# Palabra para cuando se "despulsa" un botón interruptor

Tags: verbos, solicitud-de-término, neologismos

Una duda muy tonta que nos surgió anoche en casa: existen botones que se pulsan una vez y ya está, como los botones del ascensor, que vuelven a su estado inicial tras una pulsación; y existen botones interruptores que al pulsarlos se quedan pulsados (como metidos hacia adentro, por ejemplo) y hay que volverlos a pulsar una vez más para que vuelvan a su estado original (como los botones analógicos de encendido y apagado).

Mi mujer estaba intentando explicarle a su sobrina que la secadora tenía botones de esos, y que cuando acaba su ciclo de secado hay que apagarla "despulsando" el botón. Y claro, ya nos quedamos todos pensando en si eso estaba bien dicho o no. Fui al diccionario y me encontré con que la palabra existe, pero no con el significado que esperábamos:

> **[despulsar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DQMpXJs)**
>
> De *des-* y *pulso*.
>
> 1. tr. Dejar sin pulso ni fuerzas por algún accidente repentino. U. m. c. prnl.
> 2. prnl. desvivirse.
> 3. prnl. desus. Agitarse demasiado por una pasión de ánimo.

Yo confiaba en que la palabra podría ser un neologismo aceptable dada la primera acepción de *des-*:

> **[des-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CJuPwUn)**
>
> 1. pref. Denota negación o inversión del significado de la palabra simple a la que va antepuesto. *Desconfiar, deshacer.*

Así, se podría pensar que "despulsar" sería "revertir la pulsación realizada". La pregunta es, pues, ¿existe en español algún término que defina esta acción de "despulsar" un botón? Si no, ¿existe en la literatura o en el habla coloquial algún neologismo aún no recogido por la RAE que defina esta acción?

No añado etiquetas regionales, se aceptarán respuestas de cualquier región.

Comment: Creo que la palabra `interuptor` mejor describiria ese tipo de butón.

Comment: Dato: Los botones como los del ascensor, se llaman [pulsadores](http://www.todoascensores.com/w_files/images/285a8b_FLECHA_ROJO.png). Los que tienen varios estados son [interruptores](http://www.shoptronica.com/img/images/Interruptor%20basculante%201circ-2%20posiciones.jpg) o conmutadores. El caso de tu secador sería un pulsador de dos estados pero el verbo a usar .. ni idea.

Comment: Yo le diría a la sobrina, "Para apagar el aparato, el botón tiene que ponerse en su estado (o posición) original."  (No entendí cómo se logra esto con tu aparato -- ¿se oprime una segunda vez?  ¿O se oprime otro botón para lograr que el primer botón suba a su posición inicial?

Comment: @aparente001 sí, se oprime una segunda vez el mismo botón. Pulsas una vez y se queda metido para adentro (encendido). Pulsas una segunda vez y vuelve a su posición inicial (apagado). Busco el término para esta segunda pulsación del mismo botón que lo devuelve a su estado inicial.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - Terminología difícil pero buen diseño mecánico.  Con nuestra lavadora, se jala un gran botón.  Como se rompió el mecanismo hace varios años, tenemos que usar una pinza para jalar. // *Se apaga el aparato apretando una segunda vez, para que el botón ya no esté metido.*

Answer (score 5):

Yo usaría:

Desapretar

> [**desapretar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CSf8WCF)
>
> 1. tr. Aflojar lo que está apretado. U. t. c. prnl.
> 2. tr. desus. Sacar a alguien del aprieto en que se halla.

o tambien, simplemente, soltar.

> [**soltar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YJIP8Pu)
>
> 1. tr. Desatar o desceñir.
> 2. tr. Dejar ir o dar libertad a quien estaba detenido o preso. U. t. c. prnl.
> 3. tr. Desasir lo que estaba sujeto. Soltar la espada, la cuerda. U. t. c. prnl. Soltarse los puntos de una media.
> 4. tr. **Dar salida a lo que estaba detenido o confinado.** Soltar el agua. U. t. c. prnl. Soltarse la sangre.
> 5. tr. Hacer al vientre evacuar con frecuencia. U. t. c. prnl.
> 6. tr. Romper en una señal de afecto interior, como la risa, el llanto, etc.
> 7. tr. Explicar, descifrar, dar solución. Soltar la dificultad, el argumento.
> 8. tr. desprender (‖ echar de sí). Este jersey suelta pelo.
> 9. tr. coloq. Decir con violencia o franqueza algo que se sentía contenido o que debía callarse. Soltar un juramento, una desvergüenza.
> 10. tr. desus. Perdonar o remitir a alguien el todo o parte de lo que debe.
> 11. tr. desus. Relevar a alguien de cumplir algo.
> 12. tr. desus. Anular, quitar.
> 13. prnl. Adquirir agilidad o desenvoltura en la ejecución o negociación de las cosas.
> 14. prnl. Empezar a hacer algo. Soltarse a hablar, andar, escribir.

USO:
Definitivamente se usa mas frecuentemente la palabra "soltar" en literatura en este contexto. Por ejemplo, hablando del botón del ratón:

> El relevo o apertura del circuito, ocurrido al liberar o **soltar** el
>   pulsador.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clic_(inform%C3%A1tica)

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta! ¿Podrías citar algún texto que los use en el sentido solicitado? Por otro lado, ¿a cuál de las acepciones de "soltar" haces referencia?

Comment: No hay problema. La #4, pienso que sería la mas apropiada. Buscaré un texto.

Comment: En tal caso, y siguiendo lo comentado por @CarlosAlejo, sería bueno destacatar las acepciones que te parece que encajan con el significado buscado. Más que nada porque _soltar_ tiene un montón de ellas.

Comment: El problema con "soltar" es que, según el ejemplo que indicas, se usa cuando has mantenido pulsado el botón. En el caso del botón interruptor que comento, cuando pulsas el botón la primera vez, al soltarlo se queda pulsado y la máquina se queda encendida. Tienes que pulsarlo una segunda vez para dejar la máquina apagada. Es decir, el verbo que busco se correspondería con esa segunda pulsación, y no con la acción de dejar de presionar un botón que estabas manteniendo presionado.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Ya veo. Como la función de 'toggle'. La palabra 'desapretar', depronto cabe mejor en este caso, porque queda 'apretado' y para librar el botón se 'desapreta'. Depronto librar puede ser otra palabra, como 'disengage' en inglés.

Comment: El comentario de @lois6B lo describe muy bien: Los botones como los del ascensor, se llaman **pulsadores**. Los que tienen **varios estados son interruptores o conmutadores**. En cualquier caso al **apretar** se pasa a un estado y al **soltar**, si es un botón vuelve al estado inicial, y si es un **interruptor** se queda en el estado al que llegó al pulsarlo.

Answer (score 3):

Coincido en que funcionalmente la acción que buscas se especifica en inglés como *to [toggle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toggle)*, para cuya alternancia quizás cuadre bien

> [***conmutar***](https://dle.rae.es/?id=AMC9Dku) un botón
>
> 1. tr. Cambiar una cosa por otra
>
> 6. tr. Electr. Cambiar el sentido de una señal o corriente eléctrica.

Answer (score 1):

En ingeniería y áreas técnicas, es más útil determinar el cambio de estado, consecuencia de accionar cualquier control, sean botones, palancas, interruptores, o sensores digitales de diversa índole.

Dado que en la mayoría de los casos los botones se usan para accionar un interruptor de algún circuito sea de potencia o de control; entonces decimos que el botón (y por ende está el circuito) está **"abierto"** o **"cerrado"**.

En los estudios de tiempos y movimientos para optimización cibernética, accionar un botón es una actividad compuesta de tres **triblits** o acciones atómicas:

1. Presionar
2. Sostener
3. Soltar/liberar

Últimamente está en boga asociar distintos cambios de estado o "consecuencias" a cada uno de los triblits, por ejemplo, pulsar el botón de tu iPhone

1. **al presionar** activa un cronómetro para detectar el umbral de detección de "sostener"
2. **al sostener** ordena activar a Siri. Si el cronómetro activado al presionar supera un umbral de tiempo entonces  opcional, ordena invertir el estado de potencia del dispositivo (prendido/apagado)
3. **Al soltar** dispara todas las aplicaciones registradas como observadores del evento "pulsar botón del iPhone" para que puedan realizar sus tareas, por ejemplo enviar datos de tu localización a Facebook y cmlambiar tu presencia en chats, etc.

Comment: Las acciones de "presionar", "sostener" y "soltar" se ejecutan en cada pulsación del botón interruptor; lo que yo busco es cómo denominar a la pulsación de dicho botón que devuelve el circuito a su estado de "apagado" (no sé si se corresponde con que el circuito esté abierto o cerrado). Entiendo por tu respuesta que la acción de esa segunda pulsación no tiene un nombre específico, a menos que quieras decir que podemos usar los términos "abrir" o "cerrar" el circuito. Buscaba algo más coloquial, pero igual podría valerme.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurren estas 2 posibilidades:

- **Habilitar** :: **Deshabilitar** el botón/interruptor
- **Activar** :: **Desactivar** el botón/interruptor